# Current InvocationCount in TestNG

Tags: eclipse, testng

I have a method to be tested using TestNG and I have marked it with below annotations:

```
@Test(invocationCount=10, threadPoolSize=5)
```

Now, in my test method I would like to get the current invocationCount that is being executed. Is that possible? If yes, then I would be glad to know how.

More proper example:

```
@Test(invocationCount=10, threadPoolSize=5)
public void testMe() {
   System.out.println("Executing count: "+INVOCATIONCOUNT); //INVOCATIONCOUNT is what I am looking for
}
```

For reference, I am using TestNG plugin in Eclipse.

Answer (score 9):

You can use TestNG dependency injection feature by adding **ITestContext** parameter in your test method. Please refer to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection.

From the ITestContext parameter, you can call its **getAllTestMethods()** which returns array of **ITestNGMethod**. It should returns array of only one element, which refers to the current/actual test method. Finally, you can call **getCurrentInvocationCount()** of ITestNGMethod.

Your test code should be more-less like the following sample,

```
@Test(invocationCount=10, threadPoolSize=5)
public void testMe(ITestContext testContext) {
   int currentCount = testContext.getAllTestMethods()[0].getCurrentInvocationCount();
   System.out.println("Executing count: " + currentCount);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current invocation count as mentioned below

```
public class getCurrentInvocationCount {
int count;

 @BeforeClass
 public void initialize() {
     count = 0;
  }

 @Test(invocationCount = 10)
 public void testMe()  {
   count++;
   System.out.println("Current Invocation count "+count)

  }
 }
```

I know this is a some kind of stupid way. However it will server your purpose. You can refer testNG source class to get actual current [invocationCount](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html)

Comment: Thanks for the effort Vikram. However, the approach you mentioned above will be useful only if the test is run under a single thread. As you see in my question, I have annotated the test method with `threadPoolSize=5` and that makes the above approach unusable in these circumstances. I tried by making that `static` and `volatile` as well, but that didn't work

Comment: Did you looked at the actual class link which I have given you?

Comment: I have gone through the documentation (not the actual source code though), but didn't find any provision to retrieve the current invocationCount

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
public class getCurrentInvocationCount {

  AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);

  @Test(invocationCount = 10, threadPoolSize=5)
  public void testMe()  {
   int count= i.addAndGet(1);
   System.out.println("Current Invocation count "+count)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get by calling `getCurrentInvocationCount()`  method of [`ITestNGMethod`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/ITestNGMethod.html)

Comment: Pete, can you please elaborate on how ITestNGMethod.getCurrentInvocationCount() can be used? The docs dont speak about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put 2 parameters in `@Test` method:

1. **`java.lang.reflect.Method`**

   Use [**`.getName()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getName--) to get current method name.
2. **`ITestContext`**

   Use [**`.getAllTestMethods()`**](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/6.11/org/testng/ITestContext.html#getAllTestMethods--) to get all test methods. Then use `forEach` to extract them by `ITestNGMethod` and compare with `.getName()` in point 1.

Finally, use [**.getCurrentInvocationCount()**](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/6.11/org/testng/ITestNGMethod.html#getCurrentInvocationCount--) to achieve this.

```
@Test(invocationCount=10)
public void testMe(ITestContext context, Method method) {
    int invCountNumber = 0;
    for(ITestNGMethod iTestMethod: context.getAllTestMethods()) {
        if(iTestMethod.getMethodName().equals(method.getName())){
            invCountNumber = iTestMethod.getCurrentInvocationCount();
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(invCountNumber);
}
```

Following import:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestNGMethod;
```

Answer (score -1):

When you use invocationCount the test is run like for loop.
I found this to be the easiest way to get the count of test executions.

```
int count;
@Test(invocationCount = 3)
 public void yourTest()  {
   count++;
   System.out.println("test executed count is: " + count)

  }
```